# How to scroll through elastic query results, python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm querying my elastic search server and limiting it to 100 results, but there could be a potential of 5000+ results, but for speed I don't want to overload the users connection trying to send it all in bulk.

```
data = es.search(index=case_to_view, size=100,body={
   "query": {
       "range" : {
           "someRandomFIeld" : {
               "gte" : 1,
           }
       }
   }
})
```

This is doing two things, getting me results that have the field type and only getting the results where that field type exists if its value is greater than equal to 1.

```
data['hits']['total'] # 5089
```

How do I let the user get the next lot of results from the same query, ie. The next 100, previous 100, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to utilize the "from" and "size" properties.

You can see it here in the 7.0 documentation.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

ex :

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you can only page through a maximum of {index.max_result_window documents} (which defaults to 10,000) documents this way. If you ever expect to then you'll need to use either the ["Search After"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) or ["Scroll API"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)